# JWT authentification with Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, jwt, symfony-2.7, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm trying to use [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) with [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) on my Symfony 2.7 application.

Basically, the FOSUserBundle config works fine: I properly load my fixtures and if I try to login via the login form it succeeds.

Getting the token from the login_check also works. Then I put the Authorization header with "Bearer " in the header and try to access to another page. It always result with a 401 response.

Has anyone any leads about what could be the problem or how to proceed to debug?

Here's my config:

```yaml
# app/config/config.yml

# DunglasJsonLdApi
dunglas_json_ld_api:
    title:       %api_name%
    description: %api_description%
    default:
        order: DESC

# FOSUserBundle
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm
    firewall_name: api
    user_class:    ApiBundle\Bundles\UserBundle\Entity\User

# LewikJWTAuthentificationBundle
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: %kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
    public_key_path:  %kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
    pass_phrase:      %jwt_pass_phrase%
    token_ttl:        86400
```

```yaml
# app/config/routing.yml

# DunglasJsonLdBundle
api_doc:
    resource: @DunglasJsonLdApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml
    prefix:   /api

api:
    resource: .
    type:     json-ld
    prefix:   /api

# FOSUserBundle
fos_user_security_login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user_security_check:
    path:     /api/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

fos_user_security_logout:
    path:     /logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

```yaml
# app/config/security.yml

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CA:          ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_CA, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:   ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security:  false

        login:
            pattern:   ^/login|^/api/login
            provider:  fos_userbundle
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                login_path:               fos_user_security_login
                check_path:               fos_user_security_check
                username_parameter:       username
                password_parameter:       password
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            provider:  fos_userbundle
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            lexik_jwt:

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Complete application available [here](https://github.com/theofidry/Incipio/tree/dev).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it works fine now. I did not change anything since the time I posted my question and before posting I rebooted my machine, restarted MySQL, nginx, PHP5-FPM and deleted Symfony cache, so I really fail to understand what happen...